# ImportError: cannot import name get_uid

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

```
import numpy
from keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.utils import np_utils

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = mnist.load_data()

plt.subplot(221)
plt.imshow(X_train[0], cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
plt.subplot(222)
plt.imshow(X_train[1], cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
plt.subplot(223)
plt.imshow(X_train[2], cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
plt.subplot(224)
plt.imshow(X_train[3], cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
# show the plot
plt.show()
```

Code Source: https://machinelearningmastery.com/handwritten-digit-recognition-using-convolutional-neural-networks-python-keras/

I get an ImportError when I run the code. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Please add the full traceback you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Your question could be a bit more informative. What is the exact ImportError you are getting? An ImportError usually means that your Python script can't import the libraries or files you are including at the top. Please check that the libraries mentioned in lines 1-7 are indeed installed in your system and accessible to your Python script.